# Problems using joined objects as a boolean cutter

Tags: modifiers

I used 3 objects to create the shape I wanted to create a hole in another object. I joined the three objects into one but when I do the boolean operation it leaves a hole that looks like I used the three objects individualy. How do I keep this from happening?

[image: Separate objects]

[image: joined objects]

[image: hole left by joined objects]

Comment: I guess your boolean object has some problems, like inner faces... by the way, you could easily create your shape without any boolean modifier

Comment: care to elaborate?

Comment: please share your file so that we cas see what's your problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to start with three different objects just simply start with one object and add the Bevel Modifier.

Comment: I've been messing around with the bevel modifier and the bevel tool and haven't been able to get this exact result. Since it's so easy care to explain how you would go about it?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the topology of the object you used as boolean object is bad (probably some inner face?). Here is a way to do it without boolean:

[image]

Comment: Cool thanks for taking the time to demonstrate! this is helpful :)